# Object is clipping at certain angles

Tags: materials, camera

I want to create a figure in which neurons are shooting out of an image. At certain angles, the objects start clipping. The set of cylinders that represent neurons are clipping. It doesn't matter what angles I change, it still happens. I can change the angle of the image, objects, and camera and same thing. I've also tried changing the clipping distance. Help!

The first image is good except the clipping.
The second image is an angle that didn't clip , but the objects need to be perpendicular to the image.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please give more details. What objects are clipping? It depends on what angle? camera view angle? Angle relative to another object? What do you mean when you say 'clipping'? What result do you want to achieve and what steps have you taken?
Also might be helpful to post other screenshots of your scene from different perspectives, wireframes, setups, etc.
With the current amount of information you are giving in your question, I doubt anyone would be able to give you a solution.

Comment: @AlexandreMarcati The set of cylinders that represent neurons are clipping. It doesn't matter what angles I change, it still happens. I can change the angle of the image, objects, and camera and same thing. I will try to add more info on the post! Thank you.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.